# How to create Generic Class which takes "System.Web.UI.Page" and "System.Web.UI.UserControl"?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic classes

```
public class BasePage<T>
{
    public BasePage() { }
    public BasePage(T _info) { PageBase = _info; }
    public T PageBase { get; set; }
}
```

And I have 2 class that it inherit from BasePage class

```
public class PageClass : BasePage<System.Web.UI.Page> {}
public class UserControlClass : BasePage<System.Web.UI.UserControl> {}
```

In UserControlClass class, everything no problems but in PageClass class having a problem I can't use ViewState.
Example :

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ViewState["AntiXsrfTokenKey"] = PageBase.Page.ViewStateUserKey;
   ViewState["AntiXsrfUserNameKey"] = Context.User.Identity.Name
}
```

Why it does not exist ?

> The name 'ViewState' does not exist in the current context

Comment: have you tried `base.ViewState`?

Comment: @Heberda, yes, I have but still haven't this method.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
   ViewState["AntiXsrfTokenKey"] = PageBase.Page.ViewStateUserKey;
   ViewState["AntiXsrfUserNameKey"] = Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

to

```
PageBase.ViewState["AntiXsrfTokenKey"] = PageBase.Page.ViewStateUserKey;
PageBase.ViewState["AntiXsrfUserNameKey"] = Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I think can't do because "The property 'System.Web.UI.Control.ViewState' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible"